# BadParcelableException:Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.facebook.c.n

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I export to apk, and I install on my phone. When I click fb_button, I got these errors. I tried to connect to the phone from eclipse, and install this app. It's work. So I don't understand what the problem is. Please help me!

Comment: I use Facebook SDK 4. It's facebook's problem??

Answer (score 4):

If you are using proguard, add this rule to `proguard-rukes.pro` file:

```java
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```